# I have a ball that intersects a cylinder and I need the volume. How do I do it?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have an exam coming up and I am stressing out about it really hard. I don't even know how to actually do this. Is it a triple integral?

I have a ball $\{(x,y,z)|x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 9\}$ and a cylinder $\{(x,y,z) | x^2 + y^2 \leq 5,  0 \leq z \leq 3\}$. The volume V is obtained by intersecting the ball and the cylinder. Compute V.

Comment: It's very easy, cf. http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelring or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalRing.html.

Comment: What volume here is exactly being referred to here,  there are volumes that are obtained by intersection. One volume outside the cylinder and inside sphere and many more.

Comment: @Mann http://imgur.com/hyLXzXC this is the question taken right out of the paper, any idea.

Comment: So it is very different from a problem that has a ball intersected by a plane? I'm just doing as someone suggested up there, getting the two volumes and then taking one from the other? Like with geometry?

Comment: Your definition of the cylinder doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to set it up in cylindrical coordinates to get

$\;\;\;\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{9-r^2}r\;drd\theta$.

Another way to do this is to note that the solid is made up of a cylinder with a spherical cap on top,

so the volume is given by

$\displaystyle V=V_1+V_2=\pi(\sqrt{5})^2(2)+\int_2^3\pi(9-z^2)dz=10\pi+\frac{8}{3}\pi=\frac{38\pi}{3}$

Comment: That looks great @user84413! How did you manage to get these limits, though? I think that double integral is probably what my lecturer was asking for.

Comment: @user113463 I used the fact that the base of the cylinder is the region bounded by a circle with center at the origin and radius $\sqrt{5}$ to get the limits of integration, and I used that $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ gives $r^2+z^2=9$ so $z=\sqrt{9-r^2}$ to get the height of the solid.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with picking convenient coordinate system. Since the $Oz$ axis is an axis of symmetry for both of the bodies, let's consider cylindrical coordinate system $(r, \theta, z)$ with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$.

Now the ball $B$ is described as $r^2 + z^2 \leq 3^2$ and the cylinder as $r^2 \leq 5, 0 \leq z \leq 3$. Note how nicely $\theta$ disappeared.

The volume V is given by this tripple integral:
$$
V = \iiint\limits_{\substack{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 3^2\\x^2+y^2\leq 5\\0 \leq z \leq 3}} dxdydz = \iiint\limits_{\substack{r^2+z^2 \leq 3^2\\r^2\leq 5\\0 \leq z \leq 3}} rdrd\theta dz = 2\pi \iint\limits_{\substack{r^2+z^2 \leq 3^2\\r^2\leq 5\\0 \leq z \leq 3}} rdrdz.
$$
Since integral function and region don't depend on $\theta$ the integral became double and $2\pi$ arose from integrating by $\theta$.

$$
V = 2\pi\int\limits_0^3 dz \int\limits_0^\sqrt{\min(5,9-z^2)} rdr =
2\pi\int\limits_0^3 \frac{\min(5,9-z^2)}{2} dz =
2\pi\int\limits_0^2 \frac{5}{2} dz +
2\pi\int\limits_2^3 \frac{9-z^2}{2} dz = \\ =
10\pi + \frac{8\pi}{3} = \frac{38\pi}{3}
$$